How to setup deployments from Gitlab to EC2 via AWS CodeDeploy?
I have a .NET API that is hosted on GitLab I would like to setup deployments to an EC2 instance in AWS.  I've used CodeDeploy in the past and it was a nice simple way to maintain my app, but I am dealing with some code being hosted on GitLab instead of GitHub and I do not see a way to use CodeDeploy for this task.
Is there an easier way or alternative way you would suggest a simple "deploy on merge" type of AWS pipeline for GitLab code? Or am I missing something when it comes to linking GitLab into AWS CodeDeploy.
